# Do I need to disable social media logins if users don't give permission to track on iOS14?

Tags: ios, ios14, apptrackingtransparency

I've implemented the GoogleSignIn, Firebase and Facebook in my app and I'm uncertain what the upcoming iOS 14 Tracking Transparency changes will mean.

One of the points Apple considers as reason for asking permission to track is:

> Placing a third-party SDK in your app that combines user data from your app with user data from other developers’ apps to target advertising or measure advertising efficiency, even if you don’t use the SDK for these purposes. For example, using an analytics SDK that repurposes the data it collects from your app to enable targeted advertising in other developers’ apps.

So, how do I find out if Google or Facebook is actually tracking anything within their SDK  that's not in our control?

Basically I wanna know if I need to disable the social login if users don't give permission to track.

Comment: If a user denies tracking then any api that accesses the IDFA receives all zeros. So it isn't that the user is saying "please don't track me", it is that user is explicitly denying access to the advertising tracking identifier. It is like if they deny access to the camera. An app can't just use it anyway. What you do need to do, however, is review what these 3rd party frameworks do do and include that in your App Store privacy declaration (the "nutrition label")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, how do I find out if Google or Facebook is actually tracking anything within their SDK that's not in our control?

They kind of provided this type of information in their documentations:

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy)
- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/10/22/preparing-for-apple-app-store-data-disclosure-requirements/)
- [GoogleSignIn](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/app-privacy)

> Basically I wanna know if I need to disable the social login if users don't give permission to track.

Not neccessary, I believe the developers for sure are aware of these changes and working to keep their products functional even when users don't grant permission for tracking.

For example in Facebook documentation there's a note regarding login types and which of them directly requires user's permission:

> There are two scenarios for applications that use Facebook Login via the Facebook SDK: Authenticated Sign Up or Sign In, and User Data Access via Permissions. For authentication, a unique, app-specific identifier tied to a user’s Facebook Account enables the user to sign in to your app. For Data Access, a user must explicitly grant your app permission to access data.

However just below this they add the following:

> Note: Since Facebook Login is part of the Facebook SDK, we may collect other information referenced here when you use Facebook Login, depending on your settings.

Thus I don't think there's a general answer for this question because it really depends on the data your app requests or operates with either directly or via third party.